# returning the key with the highest value in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I tried to modify a code in my lectures which is:

```py
[x for x in d.keys() if d[x] == max(d.values())] #It was in square-brackets which I'm not sure what it does
print(x)
```

I also tried it on a sample dict, which gave an error too so not sure what went wrong.
Error message:    print(x)
NameError: name 'x' is not defined

So I tried to turn it into the code below because I have difficulty understanding the code when it's stuffed into a line, which produces the wrong output for the key containing the largest value:

```py
result = []
for key in d.keys():
   if d[key] == max(d.values()):
      result.append(key)
print(result)
```

PS, I know there's a simpler way using dict.get or even using pandas but I don't fully understand it so I'm avoiding it and staying with the basic coding method.

More edits:
The list of the dictionary is below: the second code prints out "VIC" (largest value in 98) rather than "NSW" which largest value is 100

Actual code:

```
result = []
for key in humidity_for_states.keys():
   if humidity_for_states[key] == max(humidity_for_states.values()):
      result.append(key)
print(result)
```

Dictionary I have:

```
{'NSW': [81.0, 82.0, 99.0, 100.0, 96.0, 63.0, 85.0, 100.0, 83.0, 50.0, 83.0, 100.0, 90.0, 75.0, 58.0, 100.0, 70.0, 67.0, 100.0, 63.0, 57.0, 45.0, 57.0, 56.0],
 'QLD': [65.0, 69.0, 64.0, 80.0, 68.0, 78.0, 60.0, 77.0, 99.0, 72.0, 64.0, 71.0, 61.0, 76.0, 64.0, 44.0, 91.0, 72.0, 64.0, 41.0, 67.0, 32.0, 40.0, 37.0, 64.0, 56.0, 36.0, 37.0, 71.0, 33.0],
 'VIC': [92.0, 97.0, 94.0, 93.0, 65.0, 79.0, 83.0, 98.0, 70.0, 64.0, 86.0, 84.0, 71.0, 58.0, 63.0, 70.0, 85.0, 82.0, 46.0, 65.0, 94.0, 88.0],
 'SA': [52.0, 52.0, 57.0, 53.0, 54.0, 84.0],
 'WA': [19.0, 89.0, 53.0, 40.0, 45.0],
 'NT': [69.0, 64.0, 70.0, 67.0]}
```

Comment: Without knowing what error you got, we can't tell what you did wrong.  Both code snippets above are correct, so it must be the data you fed in.

Comment: What was the set of inputs you tried that failed? That code (though not optimal with unnecessary `O(n^2)` time complexity) works on my side.

Comment: Sorry guys, just chucked the error messaged in there, as for the second code, I had a larger value in one of my keys but instead, it printed out another key

Comment: Could you share that "larger" value along with the other values? We wouldn't get anything from just english sentences, we need actual code, actual input.

Comment: You can't print a variable that only exists in the context of a list comprehension, like the one on the first line of your first example. The `x` in `print(x)` isn't defined at that point, it only exists during the execution of the list comprehension. And you don't store the resulting list in a variable either, so you end up with nothing.

Comment: The simplest way is `max(d, key=d.get)` (or equivalently, `max(d, key=d.__getitem__)`). If you need *all* the keys when there's a tie, it's `maxval = max(d.values())`, `maxkeys = [k for k, v in d.items() if v = maxval]`. `O(n)` either way (though twice the work in the latter case, it's just two `O(n)` steps, which is still `O(n)`).

Comment: Mind you, it's not just "stuffed into a single line", a list comprehension is something entirely different from a regular `for` loop.

Comment: @Grismar So what can you do with a list comprehension then, if you can't store the value?

Comment: Thanks ShadowRanger, but I just don't understand the max(d.keys(), key=d.get) and our lecturer refused to go into more details as it's not examinable. I get the max function but the d.get doesn't make a lot of sense for me

Comment: The data you pasted isn't a dictionary. A dictionary is `{"a": 34, "b": -4, "c": 18}`. Also, you don't need to rely on your lecturer just to understand things, it is now a great time to live if you want to learn as the internet can guide you, even better than what your lecturer does. Reading this [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) would explain it to you. If you are afraid of list comprehensions, time to explore something new by reading this [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), no need of a lecturer.

Comment: My bad, It was a dictionary but to make it more pleasing I used a for loop that prints the key and the values.
```py
for key in dict:
   print(key, dict[key])
```
something like that

Comment: It's only for here or at the very end where everything is done and I have to adjust the presentation of my work to the follow the instructions. I work with the original dictionary

Comment: btw, @ShadowRanger, I tried using the code you suggested and it returns the same key as the code I tried above

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode, my apologies, I thought the dictionary's purpose here was supposed to show that it produced the wrong output but then I released people might want to try to see where my code went wrong. I've just fixed it

Comment: @NLT: Yes, they both get the correct answer, yours is just *much* slower as the size of the input increases, because it keeps recomputing the `max`, which makes the overall cost `O(n²)`, where mine (which does it outside the loop) stays `O(n)`. Going from 100 elements to 1000, mine increases the work done by ~10x; yours increases it by ~100x. Yours would be massively improved by simply caching `max(d.values())` to a local outside the loop, and using the local instead of recomputing the `max` over and over.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Did you get "VIC" as the output? Since I keep getting it but the key that contains the max value is supposed to be "NSW" where the max is 100 compared to VIC's 98.

Comment: @NLT: Sigh... You misrepresented the contents of the values (as if they were mere scalars). Yes, your code doesn't work right now because comparing `list`s is lexicographic; it's comparing the first element, and only looking further if they're equal (it keeps comparing until two elements differ, then selects the `list` with the largest element in that position). This is why you need to include a [MCVE] from the beginning.

Comment: This is how you'd do it choosing based on which has the largest value in the associated list: `max(d, key=lambda k: max(d[k]))`

Comment: Do you want a single key with "highest value" like your text says or *all* keys with "highest value" like your code says?

Answer (score 0):

You get `VIC` because you're comparing the lists their normal way, i.e., lexicographically. You want to compare them by their max value instead.

One efficient way to do that:

```
maxes = list(map(max, humidity_for_states.values()))
maxmax = max(maxes)
result = [key
          for key, maxval in zip(humidity_for_states, maxes)
          if maxval == maxmax]
print(result)
```

Another:

```
result = []
for key, vals in humidity_for_states.items():
    maxval = max(vals)
    if not result or maxval > maxmax:
        maxmax = maxval
        result = [key]
    elif maxval == maxmax:
        result.append(key)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reshape your dictionary into a list of tuples holding max_humidity, location pairs. Since humidity is the first value, the max of this list is your winner.

```
data = {'NSW': [81.0, 82.0, 99.0, 100.0, 96.0, 63.0, 85.0, 100.0, 83.0, 50.0, 83.0, 100.0, 90.0, 75.0, 58.0, 100.0, 70.0, 67.0, 100.0, 63.0, 57.0, 45.0, 57.0, 56.0],
 'QLD': [65.0, 69.0, 64.0, 80.0, 68.0, 78.0, 60.0, 77.0, 99.0, 72.0, 64.0, 71.0, 61.0, 76.0, 64.0, 44.0, 91.0, 72.0, 64.0, 41.0, 67.0, 32.0, 40.0, 37.0, 64.0, 56.0, 36.0, 37.0, 71.0, 33.0],
 'VIC': [92.0, 97.0, 94.0, 93.0, 65.0, 79.0, 83.0, 98.0, 70.0, 64.0, 86.0, 84.0, 71.0, 58.0, 63.0, 70.0, 85.0, 82.0, 46.0, 65.0, 94.0, 88.0],
 'SA': [52.0, 52.0, 57.0, 53.0, 54.0, 84.0],
 'WA': [19.0, 89.0, 53.0, 40.0, 45.0],
 'NT': [69.0, 64.0, 70.0, 67.0]}

highest = max((max(val), key) for  key,val in data.items())[1]
print(highest)
```

Mostly. If multiple locations have the same high humidity, the one later in the alphabet wins. You could get a list in the event of a tie using `groupby`, which creates subiterators for like-valued items.

```
import itertools

# sort humidity/location pairs then use first like-valued group to choose highest
sorted_humidity_pairs = sorted(((max(val), key) for  key,val in data.items()),
        reverse=True)
for _, group in itertools.groupby(sorted_humidity_pairs, key=lambda pair: pair[0]):
    highest_group = [pair[1] for pair in group]
    break
else:
    print("no data")
    exit()
print(highest_group)
```

And if you want only one answer with each location weighted equally, you can randomly choose one.

```
import random
highest = random.choice(highest_group)
print(highest)
```